# I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3543 with Ubuntu 15.04 as dual boot but wi-fi doesn't work and it doesn't detect the mobile broadband

Tags: networking, 15.04, broadband

I bought a dell inspiron 15 3543. i installed Ubuntu 15.04 as second boot option , but it does not detect any wi-fi signal. Also it does not detect the mobile broadband when i plug it in the usb drive.I could not find any wi-fi driver or package for this model

Comment: What does   iwlist wlan0 sc    give you?

Comment: Please post output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" to your question.

Comment: Use the "Hardware Drivers" tool to check for any proprietary drivers you may need as well.  Broadcom cards don't work until you obtain extra drivers sometimes, and some mobile broadband cards don't work.

Comment: I checked the hardware Drivers but  when i select the check-box and click apply changes, it again reverts back to previous settings

Comment: @KonradGajewski iwlist wlan0 sc gives -
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: @Pilot6 the output of  lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 is -

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Comment: I asked you yo [edit] your post, but not answer in a comment.

Comment: Ok, try 'iwconfig'. Without any parameters, and give the output.

Answer (score 3):

Connect to internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: This worked for me on Dell Inspiron 15 3543 (the same computer that the one who asked has)

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` if you just installed ubuntu!

Comment: I added the command.

Comment: this works for me too